# Order of folders in PATH is not respected?

Tags: path

Currently, my path is set as follows:

```
echo $PATH
/home/au/.local/bin:/opt/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17//bin
```

I have two versions of unison: one (2.51.3) installed through my package manager, and one (2.52.1) placed in `/opt/unison/` "by hand".
I would like the command `unison` to call the version in `/opt/unison/` by default, but it does not work, despite `/opt/` being before `/usr/bin/` in PATH:

```
$ unison -version
unison version 2.51.3 (ocaml 4.11.1)
$ /opt/unison/unison -version
unison version 2.52.1 (ocaml 4.11.2)
$ whereis unison
unison: /usr/bin/unison /opt/unison /usr/share/man/man1/unison.1.gz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `/opt/unison/unison` to be found by your shell, you need to add `/opt/unison` to your `PATH`, not `/opt`:

```
/home/au/.local/bin:/opt/unison:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17//bin
```